# Advice on usability for submit buttons vs onkeyup jQuery

Tags: jquery, form-submit, onkeyup

I have a webpage where i have a table of parts and column filtering inputs above each column so people can filter the parts in the table, the jQuery works on keyup so every time they type a letter it filters the table dynamically. However the people in my office, out of habit, keep hitting Enter after typing a filter text in the box, this in turn submits the form for processing. What can i do? Disable the Enter key or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only block the enter on the fields that should *not* submit the form. Also this will need to be bound on `keypress`, rather than `keyup`.

```
$('#target').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which == '13') {
     return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: +1 - Yes, this would be the best way to go from a usability perspective AND staying consistent with what users expect. (Make sure you don't block [Enter] for *all* fields. Only the ones where it makes sense to.)